# Criterio de aplicación da resultados equivocados pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, criteria

He estado trabajando en extraer información de ciertos textos que hay en un dataframe, donde hay palabras claves que necesito colocar en una nueva columna.  El criterio no funciona de acuerdo a lo establecido.

Adjunto un ejemplo del texto:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = {'Descripcion':['1 CONT.40    H.C.  S.W.A.L.C: 3049   BOX WITH: AVENA ORIGINAL TETRA200ML BOX X 6 UNIT AVENA CANELA  TETRA200ML BOX X 6 UNIT BABY FOOD APPLE   113GR BOX X 24 UNIT BABY FOOD PRUNE  113GR BOX X 24 UNIT BABY FOOD PEACH   113GR BOX X 24 UNIT  CARAMEL SPREAD 6X']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

Este el código que he utilizado:

```
def criteria2 (row):
  if row.DESCRIPCION.find ('RED BULL')>=0:
    return ("Red Bull")
  if row.DESCRIPCION.find ('RB')>=0:
    return ("Red Bull")
  else:
    return ("Otras")

frame['Marca'] = frame.apply(criteria2,axis=1)
```

Se crea la columna Marca, pero en el texto no aparece la palabra Red Bull o RB seguida, aparece separada R B.  ¿Cómo se puede trabajar?

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, es decir, ¿Deseas que también detecte si aparece `R B` en alguna parte de la descripción? En tu ejemplo aparece `113GR BOX` ¿Debería retornar `Red Bull`?

Comment: No quiero que aparezca porque no es Red Bull.  Es un error.

Comment: Tu pregunta menciona "Se crea la columna Marca, pero en el texto no aparece la palabra Red Bull o RB seguida, aparece separada R B. ¿Cómo se puede trabajar?" Puedes explicar un poco más lo que deseas hacer, de ese enunciado entiendo lo que puse en el primer comentario

Comment: Gracias.  En el texto que se encuentra aparecen marcas de productos, entonces corro un criterio con busca el nombre de la marca y si la encuentra en la columna crea una nueva.  Sin embargo, en el criterio aparece RB no R B, lo que crea una entrada falsa.

Comment: Al copiar y pegar tu código y corregir el nombre de la columna (Lo pusiste en mayúsculas en la función pero en el `dataframe` está en minúsculas) crea una columna y en la celda dice "Otras" ¿Cómo podemos reproducir el comportamiento erroneo que mencionas?

Comment: Gracias, perdón el retraso en contestar.  Se tendría que usar el siguiente código:   if.row.Descripcion.find ('RED BULL')>=0:  y así donde aparezca la palabra DESCRIPCION se sustituye por Descripcion